# asp.net core issue adding first database migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using new asp.net core and have my classes and db context in a sep dll I have added the code acording to the docs.

```
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<solitudeDContext>(options => 


 options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") 
  ,b=>b.MigrationsAssembly("solitudedcore")));          
    }
```

But I am still getting the following error when I run the following command

> dotnet ef migrations add firstdb
>
> Your target project 'solitudeeccore' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'solitudedcore'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly.
>   Change your migrations assembly by using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g. options.UseSqlServer(connection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("solitudeeccore")). By default, the migrations assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext.
>   Change your target project to the migrations project by using the Package Manager Console's Default project drop-down list, or by executing "dotnet ef" from the directory containing the migrations project.

I have changed the drop down to the project and added the b=>b.MigrationsAssembly("solitudedcore") as directed here on EF cores github https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7869

I also included my project includes for your reference.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
```

And my appsettings files as follows

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=DESKTOP-JHIMUM4\\SQLEXPRESS2014;Initial Catalog=solitudeec;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }


}
```

Any ideas or solutions would be appreciated.

Please find my project layout here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj6RT.jpg

**Edit 1**

The below person was indeed correct it is the spelling of the dll but also you need to target the project which hosts your dll not the actual dll itself.

To create the migration in the cmd prompt call

> dotnet ef migrations add firstdb

and to push your changes out simply call

> dotnet ef database update -e Production

Comment: Thank u for all the up votes people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is spelling mistake in migration assembly name.

Your target project **'solitudeeccore'** doesn't match your migrations assembly **'solitudedcore'**.

Comment: so what should i changed

Comment: The assembly that incldues the context is solitudedccore so that is correct but I will check

Comment: @david: Try changing 'solitudedcore' to 'solitudeeccore'  in ConfigureServices function.

Comment: scratch that worked so makes since that you reference the project hosting your dll instead ;-) how does one add identy in is it as easy shame the default template is not set up same as mvc

Comment: that allowed me to create the migration but how do i commit the changes in asp.net core ?